# operator does not exist: integer = boolean

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I put inside 3 arguments
 `run_id = 10 run_version = 2 contract_id = 34`
I am trying to run it as
`node index.js run_id=10 run_version=2 contract_id=34`
 and it give me error:
    `node index.js run_id =10 run_version=2 contract_id=34
operator does not exist: integer = boolean`

It's executable nodejs module

Can't figure out where is my mistake here... In pgAdmin3 everything is working perfect.

Here is my Sql:

```
WITH q1 AS (
        SELECT ao.run_id,
               ao.run_version,
               ao.ee_id,
               ao.posting_id,
               ao.acc_standard_id,
               eec.contract_id,
               ao.wt_id,
               ao.credit_debit_ind,
               ao.account,
               SUM(ao.amount) AS suma

            FROM accounting_output AS ao

            JOIN ee_contract AS eec
              ON eec.ee_id = ao.ee_id

           WHERE ao.run_id = ${run_id}
             AND ao.run_version = ${run_version}
             AND eec.contract_id = ${contract_id}

        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
                                          ),

           q2 AS (
                  SELECT co.run_id,
                         co.run_version,
                         q1.ee_id,
                         q1.posting_id,
                         q1.acc_standard_id,
                         co.wt_id,
                         q1.credit_debit_ind,
                         q1.account,
                           ROUND(q1.suma - SIGN(q1.suma) * ABS(COALESCE(SUM(co.amount), 0))::numeric, 2) AS diff

                    FROM q1

                    JOIN calculation_output AS co
                      ON co.run_id = q1.run_id
                     AND co.run_version = q1.run_version
                     AND co.contract_id = q1.contract_id
                     AND co.wt_id = q1.wt_id

                GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, q1.suma
                                                        ),

                q3 AS (
                       SELECT DISTINCT ao.run_id,
                              ao.run_version,
                                  MAX(ao.run_line_id) OVER(PARTITION BY ao.posting_id,
                                  ao.acc_standard_id,
                                  ao.ee_id,
                                  ao.wt_id,
                                  ao.credit_debit_ind,
                                  ao.account) AS rl,
                                  q2.diff

                          FROM q2

                        JOIN accounting_output AS ao
                          ON ao.run_id = q2.run_id
                         AND ao.run_version = q2.run_version
                         AND ao.ee_id = q2.ee_id
                         AND ao.posting_id = q2.posting_id
                             AND ao.acc_standard_id = q2.acc_standard_id
                             AND ao.wt_id = q2.wt_id
                             AND ao.credit_debit_ind = q2.credit_debit_ind

                         WHERE q2.diff != 0
                                           )

                 INSERT INTO accounting_output

                      SELECT ao.run_id,
                             ao.run_version,
                              (
                               SELECT MAX(run_line_id)

                                 FROM accounting_output

                                WHERE run_id = ao.run_id
                                  AND run_version = ao.run_version) + row_number() OVER() AS run_line_id,
                                      posting_id,
                                      acc_standard_id,
                                      wt_id,
                                      le_acc_value_1,
                                      le_acc_value_2,
                                      le_acc_value_3,
                                      wc_acc_value_1,
                                      wc_acc_value_2,
                                      wc_acc_value_3,
                                      intra_acc_value_1,
                                      intra_acc_value_2,
                                      intra_acc_value_3,
                                      treatment_acc_value_1,
                                      treatment_acc_value_2,
                                      treatment_acc_value_3,
                                      ee_acc_value_1,
                                      ee_acc_value_2,
                                      ee_acc_value_3,
                                      wt_acc_value_1,
                                      wt_acc_value_2,
                                      wt_acc_value_3,
                                      credit_debit_ind,
                                      account,
                                      account_desc,
                                      sub_account,
                                      sub_account_desc,
                                      ee_cost_center,
                                      ee_pofit_center,
                                      wt_code,
                                      wt_short_name,
                                      wt_acc_text,
                                      -q3.diff,
                                      cost_center_desc,
                                      profit_center_desc,
                                      ee_id

                               FROM q3

                               JOIN accounting_output AS ao
                                 ON ao.run_id = q3.run_id
                                AND ao.run_version = q3.run_version
                                AND ao.run_line_id = q3.rl
```

And this is my index.js page:

```
    // const Promise = require('bluebird');
const database = require('./database');
const args = require('parser')(process.argv);

const MODULE_NAME = 'ACC-ROUND';
const sqlQuery = database.query;
const sqlFiles = database.files;

(async function main() {
  try {
    console.time('Calculation done');
    await sqlQuery.none(sqlFiles.accRound, args);
    console.timeEnd('Calculation was done successfully');
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message || e);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}());
```

Comment: The codes in your question are not easily testable. You might want to read the help page on how to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you do this, there is a big chance that you find the problem yourself. Or if you don't, other people have a much easier time trying to figure it out.

Comment: What is the `parser` that you have required?

Comment: Add `console.log(run_id, run_version,contract_id)` to query caller to be sure that parser passed parameters correct.